# Vim configuration throwing errors on one machine but not the other

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

What might cause Vim to throw errors on one machine but not the other, considering both systems have identical vim configuration?

I have two Mac OS X Lion machines both running the default vim binary that ships with the OS.

I keep my .vimrc and .vim directory in a git repo. However, starting vim on one of these machines throws an error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>41_CreateMaps..<SNR>41_DefineVariables..AutoClose#DefaultPairs..AutoClose#ParsePairs:
line   18:
AutoClose: Bad pair string - a pair longer then two character
line   19:
E121: Undefined variable: a:sring
E15: Invalid expression: " `- String: " . a:sring
line   20:
 `- Pair: «» Pair len: 4
```

I keep my plugins organized using the [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git) plugin. The error appears to be caused by the AutoClose plugin.

For the sake of austerity, I removed the vim directory and all .vim files in my home directory then sourced everything from the repo and reinstalled the plugins, but the error remains.

I should add that the issue does not come up when launching MacVim, only vim in terminal.

Since vim comes preinstalled with Mac OS X Lion and my other machine (running the same version of Mac OS) does not generate those errors whilst using the same settings, I'm left clueless as to where to look..

In case it makes any difference, both machines have MacVim installed but the error only shows on one of them and only when launching vim from command line.

Comment: Is it isolated to the "AutoClose" plugin? Also, is it possible there's a dependency loading one plugin before another within vim instead of MacVim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because the file is in a different encoding (latin1 vs UTF-8) than VIM expects.

If you put `scriptencoding utf-8` at the top of your .vimrc (assuming your vimrc is actually encoded in UTF-8, use ISO-8859-1 if it's encoded in Latin1), everything from that point on should be properly recognised.

To see more documentation about this feature, type `:help scriptencoding` in vim.

(source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_LANG_to_UTF-8 and vim manual)

Comment: I added `scriptencoding utf-8` as you suggested but the error still happens.

Comment: I think you need to put it in the plugin that's causing errors. And tell the plugin's writer :)

Comment: That worked, cheers! I'm curious, based on the error, how did you determine that the issue was with the encoding?

Comment: It says the "«»" pair has a length of 4. This only happens in multi-byte encodings.